# Avoid Resubmit data cakephp page when refresh

Tags: security, cakephp

i am fighting from some days about avoing resubmit data in a cake view when i refresh the page.

I will explain the data process

1. One view with an  to /quotes/select/
2. saving data in function select
3. When i arrive to the page select.ctp i have the problem on the refresh. Everytime i refresh a new quote is saved into the DB.

In this case no forms. Is there a solution?

Working on this matter i found the Security Component and i would like to use for the "Forms". I tried to use but i get the following error:

Missing Helper
Error: SecurityHelper could not be found.

Error: Create the class SecurityHelper below in file: app/View/Helper/SecurityHelper.php

Where can i find it? Thank in advance.

Comment: Does your table has any distinct field like "email" or something else ? If so you can save those data only once from the query you are saving those data. There might be alternate way..but you can avoid multiple saving from saving function in case you  have distinct..else you have to go with alternate way.

Comment: no distint field, just the id and the hash are unique. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you have something similar to this:

```
if ($this->Quotes->save($quote)) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('Your quote has been saved.'));
}
```

You can add a redirect to the same page which will clear the POST request that is left in the browser

```
if ($this->Quotes->save($quote)) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('Your quote has been saved.'));
    return $this->redirect([]); // <----- Redirects to same page
}
```